# Selenium. Как получить данные, на основе предыдущей выборки

Tags: python, selenium

Есть код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Bakeries')

name = ["Pat-a-Cake", "Chef Bakers2", "Just Bake", "S Baking Co2"]
storenames = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "store-name")
vv =[x.text for x in storenames if x.text in name]
if vv:
    result = vv[0]
    #result = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "cntanr").text
else:
    result = 'No'
print(result)
```

Код находит из моего списка name, первый с верху магазин - его название. Но мне нужно по этому условию вывести все данные магазина.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне вывести результат другого класса ("cntanr")?
Спасибо!

Comment: Хоть и не разбираюсь селенимуме сначала ищем все li class="cntanr" м на основе этой выборки ищем нужные нам данные а также "store-name". Могу показать, но это будет не селенимум

Comment: Если не сложно, можешь показать? Может самому удастся переформатировать в язык Селениума. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:101.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/101.0',}
name = ["Pat-a-Cake", "Chef Bakers2", "Just Bake", "S Baking Co2"]
res = requests.get('https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Bakeries', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
for itm in soup.find_all('li', class_="cntanr"):
    if itm.h2.text.strip() in name:
        print(itm.h2.text.strip())
        print(itm.find('span', class_="cont_fl_addr").text)
        print(itm.find('div', class_="attr_clss").text.strip())
        print(itm['data-href'])
        break
else:
    print('No')
```

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, тут просто выводятся данные из контейнера "cntanr". А у меня нужно учесть условие....вывести первый из списка магазин, с нужным мне названием. Если нет первого магазина - проверяется второй сверху и т.д. Если вообще не находит - пишет НЕТ. Если находит по названию магазин - печатает все его данные. Вот у меня и затуп с тем, что нужно выполнить первое условие и затем, на его основе - второе. Как их объединить не понимаю:(

Comment: @Synthezx Обновил ответ.

Comment: Ух!! То что нужно!!! Спасибо большое!!!! Единственное....теперь придется мне разбираться в ....кстати, это просто питон получается?:)

Comment: селенимум это тоже питон.

Comment: Ну, собственно да....не правильно спросил. Просто твой код отличается от Селениувского.

Comment: Просто другая библиотека питона.

Comment: Не питон, a пайтон. В честь Монти Пайтон.

Comment: Понял. На самом деле я спрашивал все это ради парсера для Бинанса. https://p2p.binance.com/en/trade/sell/BNB?fiat=EUR&payment=ALL Т.е. тут по графе "Payment" я выбирал нужного (покупателя/продавца) и брал его цену лота что бы таким образом собрать нужную инфу и затем ее проанализировать....и смотрю не просто будет это адаптировать:))) Вариант с магазинами взял, т.к. на Селениуме он быстрее прогружался (быстрее виден результат), бинанс по загруженнее....С магазинами похожая ситуация....но...не тут то было:) Т.е. я так то все сделал, но у меня брался первый результат без учета "Пеймент" графы

Comment: "...В честь Монти Пайтон..." не знал. Спасибо за информацию

Comment: Селенимум для начинающих писателей парсеров то что надо порог вхождения невысокий.

Comment: А ты можешь помочь с бинансовым сайтом? Пока пробую и не получается, ты выборку делал на основе h2 как понял, а там дивы везде:) Т.е. суть такая же, по Виду платежа (мой список), выбрать самого первого (сверху) покупателя/продавца и записать его данные в эксцель (например в ячейку №1). Если в Пеймент нет такого платежа - записать NO? Если конечно не сильно тебя это обременит...

Comment: Мой приведенный пример на сайте binance.com работать не будет. Нужно отлавливать запросы.

Comment: Там все данные продавца находятся в div class="css-ovjtyv". Т.е. я подозреваю что строка выборки примерно должна быть такой: for itm in soup.find_all('div', class_="css-ovjtyv"): Но в твоем коде выборка как понял заточена на хедер h2 а тут ее нет:(

Comment: По логике да должна и вы правы(со стороны кода ошибки нет), но увы и ах только не на этом сайте. A а на селенимуме 'div', class_="css-ovjtyv" сработает.

Comment: Печально:( Понял....Попробую что ли как то объеденить два кода....эх...

Comment: Сергей. Я почти добился нужного результата, однако мне код выдает все результаты с необходымыми мне параметрами. Как "вывести на печать" только первые данные (первого продавца с моим условием)? Вот код: `код`:

GOODBanks = ["Wise", "Tinkoff2", "SEPA2"]
containers = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="css-1q1sp11"]')
for i in containers:
    if any(x in i.text for x in GOODBanks):
        result = i.text
        #price = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".css-1m1f8hn").result
        print (result)
    else:
        print ('NO')`код`

Comment: print (result) break

Comment: Разобрался. Теперь ищет как нужно. Последнее, а можно как то в контексте найденного покупателя/магазина, его позиции....взять отдельно прайс? `код`GOODBanks = ["Wise", "Tinkoff", "SEPA2"]
containers = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="css-1q1sp11"]')
for i in containers:
    if any(x in i.text for x in GOODBanks):
        result = i.text
        #price = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".css-1m1f8hn").result
        print (result)
        break
    else:
        print ('NO')`код`